# Another Android App Crashing with AdMob

Tags: android, crash, admob

I made a simple app that tests great on a slew of devices, so I thought I'd try out AdMob, but now my app crashes (the device loads an empty black screen and then crashes soon after with the message **"Unfortunately, (app) has stopped"**). Any help at this point would be huge!

***Manifest:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/z_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|
screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

***Java:***

```
package com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ErrorDialogFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7;
private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

[SEVERAL IMAGE BUTTONS] 
} 
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.rateApp:
        Intent i = new
        Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX"));
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
    return false;
} 
private boolean googlePlayServicesConnected()
{
    // Check that Google Play services is available
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    // If Google Play services is available
    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
                // Continue
        return true;
    } else // Google Play services was not available for some reason
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Services Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

***XML:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
android:background="@drawable/z_background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b_g"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/g_z" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b_f"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/f_z" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b_y"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/y_z" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b_y2"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/y2_z" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b_a"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/a_z" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b_w"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/w_z" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b_l"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/l_z" />
</LinearLayout>

//I’VE TRIED THE FOLLOWING CODE WITH AND WITHOUT ITS OWN EMBEDDED RELATIVE LAYOUT, AS SHOWN ON
//THE GOOGLE DEVELOPER’S SITE]

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   ads:adSize="BANNER"
                   ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

***Logcat Errors:***

```
10-14 19:17:56.787: E/SMD(253): DCD ON
10-14 19:17:59.027: E/memtrack(12061): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-14 19:17:59.027: E/android.os.Debug(12061): failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-14 19:17:59.177: E/dalvikvm(12072): >>>>> Normal User
10-14 19:17:59.177: E/dalvikvm(12072): >>>>> com.android.defcontainer [ userId:0 | appId:10006 ]
10-14 19:17:59.787: E/SMD(253): DCD ON
10-14 19:18:02.497: E/PersonaManagerService(732): Unable to read user list
10-14 19:18:02.627: E/LocSvc_flp(732): I/===> int flp_inject_location(FlpLocation*) line 194 
10-14 19:18:02.627: E/LocSvc_utils_q(732): D/msg_q_snd: Sending message with handle = 0x7AB2E598
10-14 19:18:02.627: E/LocSvc_utils_ll(732): D/linked_list_add: Adding to list data_obj = 
0x7AB2E598
10-14 19:18:02.627: E/LocSvc_utils_q(732): D/msg_q_rcv: Received message 0x7AB2E598 rv = 0
10-14 19:18:02.627: E/LocSvc_api_v02(732): I/---> locClientSendReq line 2332 
QMI_LOC_INJECT_POSITION_REQ_V02
10-14 19:18:02.627: E/LocSvc_utils_q(732): D/msg_q_snd: Finished Sending message with handle = 
0x7AB2E598
10-14 19:18:02.637: E/LocSvc_ApiV02(732): I/<--- void globalRespCb(locClientHandleType, 
uint32_t, locClientRespIndUnionType, void*) line 113 QMI_LOC_INJECT_POSITION_REQ_V02
10-14 19:18:02.637: E/LocSvc_api_v02(732): D/loc_free_slot:299]: freeing slot 0
10-14 19:18:06.097: E/memtrack(12130): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-14 19:18:06.097: E/android.os.Debug(12130): failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-14 19:18:06.097: I/CrashAnrDetector(732): onPackageUpdateFinished : 
com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX
10-14 19:18:06.137: I/ActivityManager(732): Killing 
11524:com.samsung.android.app.gestureservice/1000 (adj 9): empty #26
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the code you have posted that sticks out.

And while there are lots of errors in the logs you posted none of them relate to Admob.

But something seems to be tying up the UI thread when you are creating your Activity. Add some log and find out where and what that thing is.